# How many US 6th-12th grade students are learning a foreign language?

Tags: group-learning, education-statistics

I'm putting together some market analysis for a business plan for language instruction for the demographic of 6th - 12th grade US students (middle through high school).

From various sources online I've been able to compile reasonably helpful statistics about the market:

- 1.2b learners worldwide
- 800m learning English
- 87m Americans learners
- 9m K-12 American learners

My target demographic, however, is 6th - 12th grade (middle - high school).

I cannot find information specific to this age group and the stats I found on `9m K-12 American learners` don't segment this group (it's a lump of 9m K-12, that's all).

Looking for information on this particular demographic of domestic (US) foreign language learners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Foreign Language Instruction in
U.S. Schools: Results of a National
Survey of Elementary and
Secondary Schools](http://c.ymcdn.com/sites/www.aatg.org/resource/resmgr/GermanIntheUS/FLANNALS_Article_2011.pdf), which was published by The American Council on the Teaching of Foreign Languages in 2011 (emphasis mine),

> At the secondary school level, an estimated
>   **10.5 million students** out of 25.7
>   million (41%) were enrolled in language
>   classes in 2008, a decrease from the nearly
>   12 million (52%) enrolled in 1997.

The report goes on to say that the term "secondary school" refers to both middle school and high school language learners.